# Change message given when deleting post from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, advanced-custom-fields, notices

So I have a custom post type called members. linked with advanced custom fields
and I've made it so if I delete a member from the custom post type it doesn't move to the trash and permanently deletes it. but I still get this message:

[image]

---

the line I'm trying to override inside `/wp-admin/edit.php` is:

```
'trashed'   => _n( '%s post moved to the Trash.', '%s posts moved to the Trash.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] ),
```

the code I've tried inside `functions.php` to change it is as follows:

```
add_filter( 'post_trashed_messages', function( $messages )
{
    $messages['post'][2] = 'Succesfully deleted';
    return $messages;
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hook named `post_trashed_messages`, but there is the [`bulk_post_updated_messages` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/bulk_post_updated_messages/) which you can use to change the *bulk* action updated messages:

```php
add_filter( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', function ( $bulk_messages, $bulk_counts ) {
    $bulk_messages['post']['trashed'] = _n( '%s post successfully deleted.', '%s posts successfully deleted.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] );
    return $bulk_messages;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Or to target a specific post type, set the key to the post type *slug* (`$bulk_messages['<post type slug>']`) — in the example below, the post type slug is `my_cpt`:

```php
add_filter( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', function ( $bulk_messages, $bulk_counts ) {
    $bulk_messages['my_cpt'] = isset( $bulk_messages['my_cpt'] ) ? $bulk_messages['my_cpt'] : array();
    $bulk_messages['my_cpt']['trashed'] = _n( '%s post successfully deleted.', '%s posts successfully deleted.', $bulk_counts['trashed'] );
    return $bulk_messages;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Also, as you could see above, I suggest you to let users (and/or yourself) know how many posts were deleted. So make use of the `$bulk_counts['trashed']` instead of simply saying 'Successfully deleted'.. :)

### UPDATE

In reply to your comment, "*how to get rid of the undo button*", I don't see a filter for that, but you can use CSS to visually hide the button: (Just change the `my_cpt` to the correct (post type) slug.)

```css
body.edit-php.post-type-my_cpt #message a[href*="&doaction=undo&action=untrash"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this changed the message as I wanted it to.
But would u also happen to know how to get rid of the undo button?

Comment: Answer updated. You can also use CSS in combination with JavaScript to completely remove the button (from the DOM), but you'll need to try doing that on your own.. Alternatively, you could add a custom link to the [list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) and add your own message for that link without the "undo" button. That requires more coding, though.